# What does it mean for a statement to be "dichotomous"?

Tags: meaning, sentence-meaning

> It is merely a *dichotomous statement* that is meant to have a specified
>   probability of being true, in the long-run.

I understand that dichotomous means "dividing into two sharply distinguished parts", but I am not sure I understand what a "dichotomous statement" means? 
Literally it might mean something like "a statement that divides into sharply distinguished parts", but that doesn't really make sense.

Does it mean a polarizing statement? Or does it mean something completely different?

Edit: The context of the quote

> ### The theory of confidence intervals
>
> In a classic paper, Neyman (1937) laid the formal foundation for confidence
>   intervals. It is easy to describe the practical problem that Neyman saw CIs as solving.
>   Suppose a researcher is interested in estimating a parameter, which we may call θ. This
>   parameter could be a population mean, an effect size, a variance, or any other quantity
>   of interest. Neyman suggests that researchers perform the following three steps:
>
> **a.** Perform an experiment, collecting the relevant data.
>
> **b.** Compute two numbers – the smaller of which we can call L, the greater U – forming
>   an interval (L, U ) according to a specified procedure.
>
> **c.** State that L < θ < U – that is, that θ is in the interval.
>
> This recommendation is justified by choosing an procedure for step (b) such that in the
>   long run, the researcher’s claim in step (c) will be correct, on average, X% of the time.
>
> A confidence interval is any interval computed using such a procedure.
>   We first focus on the meaning of the statement that θ is in the interval, in step
>   (c). As we have seen, according to CI theory, what happens in step (c) is not a belief, a
>   conclusion, or any sort of reasoning from the data. Furthermore, it is not associated
>   with any level of uncertainty about whether θ is, actually, in the interval. ***It is merely a
>   dichotomous statement that is meant to have a specified probability of being true, in
>   the long-run.***

Comment: I think more context is needed to allow a proper answer.

Comment: I would take "dichotomous statement" as double-talk for "double-talk".

Comment: Hot Licks, I would agree, without additional information.

Comment: The quote is from a paper discussing common misunderstandings about confidence Intervals. Here is a snapshot of relevant passages, the quoted sentence is highlighted: [LINK TO IMAGE](http://i.imgur.com/G0n67e3.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The passage appears to have been written by someone with less than perfect command of the English language. In addition to grammar mistakes (e.g. "an procedure"), it contains a logical contradiction in the last two sentences.

Judging from the context, the author most likely meant to say that the statement is an *unequivocal*,  *true-or-false* proposition.

Answer (score 0):

> c. State that L < θ < U - that is, that θ is in the interval
>
> "It is merely a ***dichotomous*** statement that is meant to have a specified probability of being true, in the long-run."

You are correct in your assumption that this does have to do with two parts.

> #### Dichotomous
>
> - Involving two completely opposing ideas or things

([CD](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/dichotomous))

The author is not using this word in any special way; he/she is simply saying that statement (c) is nothing special. Statement (c) is merely a statement that is split into two parts, L & U, which are opposing values (they are opposites, as state in the original).

Comment: In the given context, it appears to mean exactly the opposite of *contradictory*.